# How to ignore capitalization with RegEx in Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++, regex

Somebody knows how to ignore capitalization with regular expression in Notepad++?

From shell it works as follows:

egrep **-i** '^(FroM|SuBjeCT|DatE): ' filename.txt

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions)

Answer (score 7):

In the Find dialog use the **Match case** checkbox to choose whether you want case-insensitive searching or not, ie. leave it UNCHECKED to ignore capitalization with NotePad++ regular expressions.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the ?i modifier.

```
(?i)(from|subject|date)
```